# Group by and find means of all numeric varables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with about a hundred variables, so the easiest way for me to get the means by group is as follows:

```
iris %>%
group_by(species) %>%
summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=T)
```

However, I also want to know the N within each mean count as well. R does not accept n() inside summarise_if.

I could manually type out each variable like this, but I have hundred of variables so that won't work.

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(mean_sl = mean(Sepal.Length), mean_sw = mean(Sepal.Width), 
mean_pl = mean(Petal.Length), mean_pw = mean(Petal.Width), n())
```

Any idea's how I can get the mean, as well as the N for each numeric variable in my dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0, we can use `across` with `summarise` where multiple functions can be applied as in a regular `summarise` as well groups or blocks of columns in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE), n = n())
```

---

Based on the OP's comments, if we need to find the number of missing values per each column along with `mean` of each column, we can have different sets of `across` (if different sets of columns are used)

```
iris %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
             across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(is.na(.)), .names = '{col}_n'))
```

or have a single `across` with different functions

```
iris %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
          list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), n = ~ sum(is.na(.)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of getting the N for each variable, instead of by group? So for example, if Sepal.Length were missing 2 values within the Species, I would see "48" next to the N for Sepal.Length for the group Setosa.

Comment: Basically, I would like to see the total non missing N's for each variable in the dataset.

Comment: I now get a lifecycle warning in case it's helpful. >>> There was 1 warning in `summarise()`.
ℹ In argument: `across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = T)`.
Caused by warning:
! The `...` argument of `across()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.1.0.
Supply arguments directly to `.fns` through an anonymous function instead.

  # Previously
  across(a:b, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  # Now
  across(a:b, \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))